# Joomla load cdn versions of jQuery and Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, cdn, joomla3.0

In Joomla 3 (specifically 3.2.1) you can load local copies of jQuery and Bootstrap Javascript Libraries by adding the line `JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');`to your template. Or load just jQuery by adding `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`

What I want to do is load CDN versions of these libraries but also have the local copies as a fallback. I know how to do this by just using Javascript but how can I do this with PHP?

I would also like to expand on this and load CDN versions of the Bootstrap CSS with local fallback.

Thank you

Comment: I wrote an answer before, however having tested it, it didn't work. I believe you have to use `Curl`. Does you server support `Curl`? I would however stick with `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` as this imports jQuery in noConflict mode automatically

Answer (score 2):

We don't know why you need both versions - CDN and local, so please excuse me, if this is not you want.

```
$url = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"; //jQuery 1.10.2 CDN URL
$header_response = get_headers($url, 1);
if ( strpos( $header_response[0], "404" ) !== false )
{
  // FILE DOES NOT EXIST SO LoADING LOCAL JQUERY
  JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
}
else
{
  // FILE EXISTS, SO DO NOTHING
}
```

URL of version 1.10.2 in my example is because Joomla 3.2.0-3.2.1 have this version of jQuery (thx to [@Lodder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1362108/lodder) for tip)

Comment: would recommend checking for jQuery 1.10.2 rather than 2.0.3 as this is the version that comes with Joomla ;)

Comment: Thank you, colleague! Edited.